# DDD + CQRS + ES: May entities or dtos be part of commands?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

Is it ok to have entities or dto's in a command in a DDD, CQRS + EventSourcing application? I think this shouldn't be done, at least no entity should be part of a command.

I try to describe the issue in words:
I have an aggregate root A which can have a list of property entities. A property entity does not have it's own aggregate root, it's just part of my aggregate root A. Additionally, one and the same property entity cannot be part of another aggregate root.

Some developer of my company thought it would be a nice way to have a `CreateAggregateA` command which holds a list of `Property-Entity` objects. The command handler creates the aggregate, adds all property entities to the list and saves the aggregate.

Additionally the `AggregateACreated` event also has the list of property entities which is also incorrect.

Is it ok to exchange the property entity with a `propertyDto` object which lives in the domain (command and handlers are in the domain)?

Or should commands always be as simple as possible.
For example just to have a `CreateAggregateA` command with only simple types (string name, string otherParameter) and we need an additional command `CreateProperty` which creates the property entity and adds it to the linked aggregate?

Is there any best practice around? I googled quite a lot but did not find a clear statement or guidance.

Any help and input is highly appreciated.

Regards,
Christian

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I'm not a DDD expert. I'm just sharing what I learned about it and some personal opinions.

---

In DDD:

1. An entity should have a unique identity during its entire lifetime.
2. It also may have some invariants to keep in a valid and consistent state during all its life cycles.

The most DDD examples I saw were implemented in a like-Hexagonal architecture where commands are directly instantiated and hydrated in a primary adapter (e.g HTTP controller) then passed to the application service or the command bus.

That said, having entities in commands may conduct you to mutate first their state with external data before doing request and/or logic validation. So, in some circumstances, 2/ can't be respected.

Also, doing that can force you to provide all entity's properties within the external data which is not always necessary.

DDD considers Value-Objects as first class citizens of the domain models and recommends using them (if they make sense to your model):

1. They don't have the same constraints as entities. So, they can be used in commands, events, and entities too.
2. They also can help you to refactor your code and keep the other objects small and simple.

In DDD + CQRS, entities handle especially the write concerns while VOs can be used as a read model.

**Conclusion:**

Implementing DDD in a project may conduct you to spend more time in design, to write many objects with different concerns, having some redundant codes, etc.
That can help you to handle business complexity and keep your model clear and under control :)

A CRUD-based solution that respects DRY and uses entities to handle differents concerns can also be efficient if your business is simple, doesn't risques to considerably involve, or it doesn't belong to the core business domain.

I hope that was helpful

Comment: DTOs, commands/queries, and their handlers belong to the application layer while events belong to the domain layer.

Comment: I highly disagree that command handlers belong to the application layer. They are part of the domain. Otherwise it would be ok to do lookups on the read side within the command handler which is not allowed in DDD CQRS. It is explained here: https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/cqrs-commands-part-domain-model/

Comment: But I think I found the answer. A entity should not be part of a command and absolutely not part of an event. Normally the command is created in the controller based on some data sent from the client as view model. An entity should not be created just with new Entity() because a Customer can't show up from thin air. So no entity can be handed over to the command. Only a dto which then can be used to create an entity within the aggregate.